# ggheatmap R script error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using this r script (https://cwcode.wordpress.com/2013/01/30/ggheatmap-version-2/ ) in order to perform a nice heatmap automatically. At the beginning, it works as expected, but if I increase the size of the dataset, it crashes. I'm not very good at R, I'm starting, so I don't know exactly what it is going on. I guess that maybe memory problems. This is the error message:

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_upviewport, as.integer(n)) :   cannot
pop the top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?) Error
in grid.Call.graphics(L_upviewport, as.integer(n)) :   cannot pop the
top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?) Error:
evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion /
options(expressions=)? Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too
deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Anyone can suggest me how to solve this issue? My input dataset has 62 columns and 16956 number of rows. If I extract the first 10000 rows, the script works fine.

Comment: Have you tried to increase `options(expressions=[...])` ? To make a long story short, if nested loops cause too many recursions, R will consider them as 'infinite'. Increasing the value of `expressions` to something high (like 100000) could solve your problem.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003021/explanation-of-r-optionsexpressions-to-non-computer-scientists

Comment: Thank you both guys for the suggestions. I've just increased expressions value and I'm checking the script now.

Comment: Well, now I don't get any error but... the plot is not produced .. no idea why because I don't have errors on screen... any other suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried to save it in a file then open it? Maybe you cannot 'show' it (like in the blog post you linked) but saving it would work. Anyway, I don't know how ggplot2 works so I can not help you if it is something internal in ggplot2...

Comment: Yes, I've tried to save it in different formats but still not working. It's a bit weird because I get the legend printed but not the heatmap :S. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: In this case you might have too much data. Imagine, with 17000 rows, even if you take 1 pixel by row, you would end in having a monstrously huge image.