# when qsub Rscript: Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?

Tags: r, recursion, infinite, qsub

I am trying to run a R script in a cluster as a job.
The R code works without problem when I run it in the R command-line, however when i submitted as job i get the following error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Execution halted
```

when:

```
write.table(x, file=paste0(test,".gff") , quote=FALSE, sep="\t", eol="\n", na="NA", dec=".", row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE)
```

I have tried with changing the `options(expressions = 500000)` and `--min-ppsize` as well, but get the same error and it is not writing the table.

Im stack and hope someone will shed some light....

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003021/explanation-of-r-optionsexpressions-to-non-computer-scientists

Comment: The related posts are not answering my question, unfortunately.