# plot thousands lines with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm tring to plot thousand lines (each line consists of 15 values) from `data` sequentially (the first line is from element NO.1 to NO.15; the second is from NO.16 to NO.30; ...) with ggplot. Here is a reproduceable code:

```
data<-data.frame(y=rnorm(95040))
p<-ggplot(data=data.frame(y=data[1:15,]),aes(x=c(1:15),y=y))+geom_line(alpha=I(1/7),size=1)
for(i in 1:(nrow(data)/15-1)){
  p<-p+geom_line(data=data.frame(y=data[(i*15+1):(i*15+15),]),aes(x=c(1:15),y=y),alpha=I(1/7),size=1)
}
```

When the loop runs at `i=621`, it reports an error:

```
Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
```

Why this happens and how to solve this plot problem (perhaps with another plot method)?

Comment: Could this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003021/explanation-of-r-optionsexpressions-to-non-computer-scientists ?

Comment: A plot with thousands of lines is useless and needlessly bloated. You cannot distinguish that many lines in a plot anyway.

Comment: Also, study the grammar of graphics. This is not how you do this task in ggplot2. Start with creating a grouping variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need something like this...

```
data<-data.frame(y=rnorm(95040))
data$x <- 1:15
data$group <- (1:nrow(data)) %/% 15
p<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y,group=group))+geom_line(alpha=I(1/7),size=1)
```